# Issue comparing letters in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, compare, letter

So... I got kind of strange problem? Im doing easy game for practice, where you try to guess the name of item. When I wanted to show the correct one after u click it, I encountered strange compare problem, so... the first letter of the string is equal to the same letter, but the rest of the string letters - returns undefinded...

This is my code and also the result / output:

```js
for (x = 0; x < wylosowaneSlowo.length; x++) {
  if (wylosowaneSlowo[x] == litera) {
    id_litery.push(x);
    console.log(wylosowaneSlowo[x], litera, id_litery[x]);
  }
}
```

1. The first char of the string: [image: first character of string]
2. The second char of the string: [image: second character of string]

Comment: So you want to see if the string is same or not?? or do you want to see if a string is there in a part of the other string??

Comment: Because [x] is not same as id_litery since you do not push to it.... And why are you pushing the index? `console.log(id_litery);`

Comment: @AlphaWolfGamer Im trying to create hangman game, so ... when someone clickc the letter, the program have to check if this letter exist in the string, and if do - then it have to check in how many places it is, then show it on the right places, and mark those places as clicked.
(Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Can you give a full example (in your question) of input `wylosowaneSlowo` and of `litera`, and expected output in `id_literary` once the loop has completed?

Comment: @epascarello Ohh... Im such a moron, problem solved... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are pushing to an array and looking at the index. So if the index has no match, you are looking at an index that is not defined.

You probably want to make an array with the possibilities and alter the index that has a match.

```js
var phrase = "Hello World";
var shown = phrase.split('').map(function (char) {
  return char.match(/[a-z]/i) ? '_' : char;
});


function guess(letter) {
  for (let i=0; i<phrase.length; i++) {
    if (phrase[i].toLowerCase() === letter.toLowerCase()) {
      shown[i] = phrase[i];
    }
  }
  console.log("guess: ", letter, " game: ", shown.join(" "));
}

guess("s");
guess("l");
guess("o");
guess("h");
guess("e");
guess("w");
guess("d");
guess("r");
```

Comment: I already fixed it after Your first comment, but still - thank you.